# How to use angular material design code & filter in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, meanjs

Hi all i want to angular material designs using `angular-material.js`. In my demo link quality input field look like to `angular material` input style,drop down and animation and filter then i tried many ways but unable to get the solution if any one knows the solution please help me.....[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/bwZONxOV0mVAbVA9Y8XH?p=preview)

**HTML:-**

```
 <div class="col-md-12">
 <md-input-container ng-cloak="" class="md-block md-inline-form inputdemoBasicUsage" flex-gt-sm>
        <label>Quality</label>
        <md-select ng-model="searchtable.colorshades.quality">
          <md-option ng-options="item.quantity as item.quantity for item in descriptionyarnqualitys">

          </md-option>
        </md-select>
      </md-input-container>
  </div>
```

**Controller:-(Filter)**

```
 $scope.getDescriptionyarnqualitys = function() {
    var qualities = {};
    angular.forEach($scope.sryarnorders, function(order) {
      angular.forEach(order.colorshades, function(shade) {
        var quality = shade.quality;
        qualities[quality]=quality;
      });
    }) 
    console.log(qualities);
    return qualities;
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

Open your console (it should **always** be opened while developing), and you'll see the following error message:

> VM320 angular.js:12722 Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'select', required by directive 'ngOptions', can't be found!

And indeed, you're putting `ng-options` on `md-option`, instead of putting it on the `md-select`, where it belongs.